# Python : how to prevent a class variable that is a function to be understood as a method?

Tags: python, django, function, methods, metaclass

I am currently implementing a django app, for this I try to use a syntax that is consistent with Django's...

So here is what I am trying :

```
class Blablabla(Model):

    #this contains Blablabla's options
    class Meta:
        sort_key = lambda e: e
```

`sort_key` is a key function (for sorting purposes), but of course, it is understood as `Meta`'s method (which is absolutely not what I want)!!!

Any workaround to this, that would still allow me to use this syntax ?

EDIT :
Just an important precision ... the code I wrote is supposed to be written by somebody that uses the library ! That's why I don't want any dirty trick. And YES in Django it is really used just for options... of course Meta IS a class, but I say "it is not seen as a class", because it is not used as a class : you don't instantiate it, you don't put class methods, only class attributes... The `Model` has a metaclass that extracts everything from this `Meta` and handles all the options declared... But that's all ! It IS just a placeholder for options.

But OK that's True I never saw an option that is a function in Django... So I'll follow **Ned** an declare this sorting function as a method of `Model` that has to be overriden ...

Comment: Check your assertion. This may be a good read for you: [Static-Aka-Class-Methods](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52304-static-methods-aka-class-methods-in-python/)

Comment: If you define it like this, sort_key will become a bound method of Meta. If that's not what you want, my question is: What are you trying to achieve then?

Comment: If you know Django, "Meta" is just an artefact, that allows to separate the options declaration from the field declarations (because fields can have any name) ! For example : 

class MyModel(Model):
    a_field = TextField()
    another_field = TextField()
    class Meta:
        an_option = 1
        another_option = "blabla"

etc ... Do you understand why this is useful ?

Comment: @user166390 : I am studying your thing, but that doesn't seem to work in my case ... It is still waiting for an instance of Meta as first argument ... don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to put `sort_key` into `Meta`?  `Meta` is used for Django options, it isn't a place to put your own methods.  Models can have methods defined on them.  I think you want something as simple as:

```
class Blablabla(Model):

    def sort_key(self, e):
        return e
```

Comment: Actually I think that might be the best solution :)
I was just thinking of considering "sort_key" as an option, so it would be a reusable sorting function, instead of being a method ...

Comment: You could make it a staticmethod on the model as well!

Comment: that's what I did ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In general,

```
class Meta(object):
    sort_key= staticmethod(lambda e: e)
```

I've no idea if whatever magic Django does to transplant ‘meta’ members copes OK with decorated methods like this, but I don't see any inherent reason why not.

Comment: I don't want to use decorator, because 'Meta' is not really supposed to be seen as a class... It's really just an option placeholder ! So using a decorator in there is not really intuitive...

Comment: Sorry, but `Meta` *is* a class, Python won't give you any leeway on that! The only alternative I can think of would be to say `sort_keys= [lambda e: e]` and access `self.sort_keys[0]` to break the connection between the function and the class.

Answer (score 0):

The OP writes in a comment "'Meta' is not really supposed to be seen as a class".  If that's the case, that is, if Django can survive when `Meta` is indeed **not** a class (a very big "if"), then it's possible to satisfy the OP's truly weird desire to avoid the simplest solution (just wrapping `stqticfunction` around the `lambda` in question).

Essentially, this requires writing a (pretty weird) **meta**-class that generates an object where attribute lookup bypasses a class's normal use of descriptor objects (every function is a [descriptor object](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm): that is, it has a `__get__` method which Python normally uses when looking up attribute on the class or an instance thereof).

The general idea of this absurd gyration would be something like...:

```
class MetaNotAClass(type):
   def __new__(mcl, clasname, bases, clasdict):
     if bases:
         usedict = {}
     else:
         usedict = clasdict
     usedict['__foo'] = clasdict
     return type.__new__(mcl, clasname, bases, usedict)
   def __getattr__(cls, atname):
      try: return getattr(cls, '__foo')[atname]
      except KeyError: raise AttributeError, atname

class NotAClass:
  __metaclass__ = MetaNotAClass


class Bah(NotAClass):
  def f(): return 'weird!'

print Bah.f()
```

Of course, anything that *expects* `Bah` to **be** a class will break (but then, you do say it's "not really supposed to be seen as a class", so that's basically what you're asking for: to break any code that believes it **is** "to be seen as a class"!-).

Comment: Or you could just define a metaclass that applies `staticfunction` to every method of a class for which it is the metaclass...

Comment: @Zack, yes, but the OP (as part of his absurd request) specifically asks how to avoid "the decorator" (and since nobody's actually proposed using decorator _syntax_, he must mean, avoiding `staticfunction`, the higher-order callable that's often used with decorator syntax, though not in the A the OP was commenting on).

Comment: I dunno, I understood him to want "staticfunction" not to appear on or near the "sort_key = lambda e: e" line.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a simple module (`meta`?) and add `sort_key` to it? Then go ahead and `include` it wherever you need it...